# Динамически изменяющийся label с пингом до ip

Tags: delphi

Есть сокет сервер и сокет клиент, как можно отобразить динамически в label пинг до подключенного ip сервера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете таймер в дополнительном потоке, по таймеру отправляете запрос, получаете результат и синхронизируете его с лэйблом в основном потоке.

Comment: таймер - в смысле TTimer?

Comment: да, он самый.  
Или не вариант?

Comment: А он работать не будет. Это известный факт. Так что Ваш совет просто вреден.

Объяснение - таймер использует стандартное апи с WM_TIMER. А оно будет работать только в главном потоке.